# "yum update" causes conflicting "libstdc++" on CentOS7

Tags: centos, yum, vps

Running `yum update` has the following output:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, replace
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: mirror.imt-systems.com
 * ius: mirrors.ircam.fr
 * remi: mirror.23media.de
 * remi-safe: mirror.23media.de
 * rpmforge: miroir.univ-paris13.fr
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package gdb.x86_64 0:7.6.1-100.el7 will be updated
---> Package gdb.x86_64 0:8.0-17.1.scylladb.1.el7.centos will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: gdb-headless(x86-64) = 8.0-17.1.scylladb.1.el7.centos for package: gdb-8.0-17.1.scylladb.1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package gdb-headless.x86_64 0:8.0-17.1.scylladb.1.el7.centos will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

=============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                                Arch                                             Version                                                                  Repository                                            Size
=============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Updating:
 gdb                                                    x86_64                                           8.0-17.1.scylladb.1.el7.centos                                           mcepl-vim8                                           277 k
Installing for dependencies:
 gdb-headless                                           x86_64                                           8.0-17.1.scylladb.1.el7.centos                                           mcepl-vim8                                           3.0 M

Transaction Summary
=============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Install             ( 1 Dependent package)
Upgrade  1 Package

Total size: 3.3 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
Running transaction check
Running transaction test


Transaction check error:
  file /usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.py from install of gdb-headless-8.0-17.1.scylladb.1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libstdc++-4.8.5-16.el7_4.1.i686
  file /usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.pyc from install of gdb-headless-8.0-17.1.scylladb.1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libstdc++-4.8.5-16.el7_4.1.i686
  file /usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.pyo from install of gdb-headless-8.0-17.1.scylladb.1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libstdc++-4.8.5-16.el7_4.1.i686

Error Summary
-------------
```

I am really unsure of what to do and I really do not want to break anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specifically need this version of **libstdc++**, you may want to remove the package that cause the issue:

```
yum remove -y libstdc++-4.8.5-16.el7_4.1.i686
```

Then run the package installation again:

```
yum install gdb -y
```

Usually, this kind of conflicts happen because of 3rd-party repositories. Here is a link on serverfault.com to disable/remove it: [How do I remove a repository of yum](https://serverfault.com/questions/314461/how-do-i-remove-a-repository-of-yum)

Comment: Funny thing is that, to see what this library... consists of, I did run an `yum remove` command but i didn't get to confirm it (wasn't going to, i am new but the words "lib" and "c++" raised a red flag). It gave an error about systemd and another common command which I can't remember now. I have since disabled the repo, had it only for the latest version of vim anyway.

Comment: Yes, like I've said: "If you don't need this specific version...". I've added a line to disable a repo so that this answer is complete.